# Can a city or a place be described as 便利?

Tags: adjectives, na-adjectives, composition

I know 便利 means something convenient or handy but can it also be used to describe a place?

Ex. 1 If City A is close to city B, can I say that city A is 便利 (because it is easy and fast to travel to city B)?

Ex. 2 If city A has lots of supermarkets, restaurants and banks, can it be described as 便利？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a city or place may be described as 便利. Both of your examples are valid.

However, your statement sounds peculiar:

> I know 便利 means something convenient or handy but can it also be used to describe a place?

I would say:

> 便利 means something convenient or handy **therefore** it may be used to describe a **characteristic** of a place

---

## Examples

- Tokyo is convenient = 東京は便利

Consider the above to be a simplified version of the following:

- Tokyo is a convenient place = 東京は便利な場所
- Tokyo is a place which is convenient = 東京は便利な場所

## 不便

You may use 不便 for the opposite effect:

- Tokyo is inconvenient = 東京は不便

Consider the above to be a simplified version of the following:

- Tokyo is an inconvenient place = 東京は不便な場所
- Tokyo is a place which is inconvenient = 東京は不便な場所